# IPP .NET CustomerQuery exclude Jobs

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

How do we filter out Jobs from a CustomerQuery with IPP .NET (QuickBooks Online)?

See this thread for reference (it seems unresolved?): 
https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=87&threadid=16282

Below are the relevant lines that *should* exlude Jobs, but it isn't working...

```
Dim cq As New Qbo.CustomerQuery
cq.IncludeJobs = False
customers = cq.ExecuteQuery(Of Qbo.Customer)(context).ToList()
```

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the DevKit.  It does not pass the IncludeJobs filter in the request body.

It will be fixed in the next release, but here is a workaround using DevDefined.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = GetQboCustomers(dataService, 1, 100, false);

public List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer> GetQboCustomers(DataServices dataServices, int startPage, int resultsPerPage, bool includeJobs)
{
    StringBuilder requestXML = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder responseXML = new StringBuilder();

    var requestBody = String.Format("PageNum={0}&ResultsPerPage={1}", startPage, resultsPerPage);
    if (!includeJobs) { requestBody += "&Filter=IncludeJobs :EQUALS: false"; }

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(dataServices.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "customers/v2/" + dataServices.ServiceContext.RealmId) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(httpWebRequest, requestBody));
    requestXML.Append(requestBody);
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] content = encoding.GetBytes(requestXML.ToString());
    using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (Stream data = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults searchResults = (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults)dataServices.ServiceContext.Serializer.Deserialize<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults>(new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd());
        return ((Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customers)searchResults.CdmCollections).Customer.ToList();
    }

}

protected string GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(HttpWebRequest webRequest, string requestBody)
{

    OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
    {
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
        SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true

    };

    consumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;

    //URIs not used
    OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://www.example.com",
                            "https://www.example.com",
                            "https://www.example.com");


    oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
    {
        Token = accessToken,
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
        TokenSecret = accessTokenSecret
    };

    IConsumerRequest consumerRequest = oSession.Request();
    consumerRequest = ConsumerRequestExtensions.ForMethod(consumerRequest, webRequest.Method);
    consumerRequest = ConsumerRequestExtensions.ForUri(consumerRequest, webRequest.RequestUri);
    if (webRequest.Headers.Count > 0)
    {
        ConsumerRequestExtensions.AlterContext(consumerRequest, context => context.Headers = webRequest.Headers);
        if (webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> formParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string formParameter in requestBody.Split('&'))
            {
                formParameters.Add(formParameter.Split('=')[0], formParameter.Split('=')[1]);
            }
            consumerRequest = consumerRequest.WithFormParameters(formParameters);
        }
    }

    consumerRequest = consumerRequest.SignWithToken();
    return consumerRequest.Context.GenerateOAuthParametersForHeader();
}
```